"Inspector Rex" episode where attacker targets people with laser
I am searching for an episode of the show Inspector Rex (Kommissar Rex in German or Il commissario Rex in Italian), the German Shepherd police dog.
It's been at least 5 years since I have seen the episode on Italian TV, probably rather 10 years.
The episode was about an attacker who used some sort of a laser gun to kill people. He was always sitting somewhere on a chair and had a contraption in front of him with the "gun". I can remember three different occasions that it was shown in that episode:

The attacker was sitting on a (white?) roof and targeting a woman (?) in an office building, through a window pane.
He was sitting on a little hill near a curved road and shot a biker as he was driving through the curve.
He sat in a shop window (facing the street?) with several hostages lying on the ground inside the shop. The dog would crawl into the shop and signal the hostages to follow him while staying flat on the floor.

I'm excited to see if someone recognizes the episode, since the series only aired in Austria, Germany and Italy, as far as I know.

I seen this episode lately it's noted as Alex Brandtner last appearance of Inspector Rex. The episode is "Strahlen der Rache" (Rays of Revenge).
I hope this helps. 

Welcome to Movies.SE! Could you explain why you believe this episode matches the question?
